# Alternative to Enzyme for unit testing in React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Since Enzyme is dead for React 18 and everyone seems to be talking about React Testing Library, for a more integration-testing approach. However, in my case I need more of a unit-testing solution to test functions within my React component:

```
export default function Chat({ userName, roomName }: ChatProps) {
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");
    const [messageList, setMessageList] = useState<SocketMessageNS.NewMessageIn[]>([]);

    const [sendSocketMessage, isConnected] = useSocketIo(userName, roomName, handleOnNewMessage);

    function handleOnNewMessage(msg: SocketMessageNS.NewMessageIn) {
        // ...
    }

    function handleOnSendMessage() {
        // ...
    }

    return (
        <div className="Chat">
            <ChatHeader isConnected={isConnected} roomName={roomName} />
            <ChatConversation data={messageList} userName={userName} />
            <ChatInput value={userInput} onChange={setUserInput} onSubmit={handleOnSendMessage} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

I want to be able to test my functions on their own, simply by calling them like you would do with Enzyme:       `wrapper.instance().handleOnSendMessage();`

It doesn't seem to be possible with React Testing Library.
What do you do when you need to test your functions with React components with spies and such?

Comment: Directly invoking the handlers was poor testing practice when Enzyme encouraged it and class-based components made them accessible. The fact that RTL discourages it and function-based components make them flat-out inaccessible _at a language level_ is helpful; test _behaviour_, not implementation. This isn't integration testing (although you can also do that with multiple components) - the isolated SUT is the _component_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think that behaviour and implementation are closely related to each other. Doesn't it make sense to want to test handleOnNewMessage() without having to mock the useSocketIo hook? Or test handleOnSendMessage() without having to trigger the user action within the ChatInput component? In fact, in doesn't make sense to me not to be able to unit test my Chat component without having to interact with its children components or services, since I already wrote tests for them.
I am coming from Angular/Karma, and my company enforced high code coverage, unit testing functions was a must do

Comment: It's the same principle as private methods. You can still get high coverage (and, more importantly, confidence that they're working now and you'll find out if they stop doing so) without invoking them directly. Which framework or even language you're testing in/with doesn't really matter.

Comment: Learn React Testing Library. It takes a different perspective than Enzyme, and it took me some time to understand it, but it should lead to more stable tests. I'd recommend looking at Kent C. Dodds' articles and videos (as well as the documentation) to understand it fully.

Answer (score 0):

React Testing Library is good to use it with Jest. That way you can achieve what you will do with Enzyme.

In these case you should use:

```
const spyObject = jest.spyOn(object, 'handleOnSendMessage');
  object.handleOnSendMessage();
  expect(spyObject).toBeCalled();
```

Comment: What object do you think `handleOnSendMessage` is a property of? And what value do you think there is on spying on a method, calling the method then asserting that you called the method?

Comment: For me the best approach should be to know if when clicking the method has been called. I don't know for sure what ChatInput does & what is its composition, but I would go with the use of `userEvent`